# Hibernate get ID from composite PK (sequence in DB) after insert

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

How I can get `ID`  generated by sequence in database, after insert record?

Hibernate config:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">masterkey</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:FB3</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SYSDBA</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_entity_mode">pojo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">2</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
  <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
  <mapping class="com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.fb.entity.MyTable"/>
  <mapping class="com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.fb.entity.Usr"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`Usr` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USR")
public class Usr {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UsrPK id;
    
    @Column(name = "FNAME", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "DTMSTMP", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp dTmStmp;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MYTABLEID")
    private MyTable myTable;

    public Usr() {}
    
    public Usr(String login, String firstName) {
       this.setId(new UsrPK(null, login));
       this.setFirstName(firstName);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
       Object[] args = { this.id.getId(), this.id.getLogin(), this.getFirstName(), this.getMyTable().getId(), getdTmStmp() };
       MessageFormat text = new MessageFormat("Object: {0} [id={1}, login={2}, firstName={3}, myTableId={4}, dTmStmp={5}");
       return text.format(args);
    }
    
    @Embeddable
    public static class UsrPK implements Serializable {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "BIGINT", unique = true)
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PK")
       @SequenceGenerator(name = "PK", sequenceName = "GEN_USR_ID", allocationSize = 1)
       private Long id;
    
       @Column(name = "LOGIN")
       private String login;
    
       public UsrPK() {}
    
       public UsrPK(Long id, String login) {
          this.setId(id);
           this.setLogin(login);
       }
    
       public Long getId() {
          return id;
       }

       public void setId(Long id) {
          this.id = id;
       }

       public String getLogin() {
          return login;
       }

       public void setLogin(String login) {
          this.login = login;
       }
    
    }
    
    public UsrPK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UsrPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Timestamp getdTmStmp() {
        return dTmStmp;
    }

    public void setdTmStmp(Timestamp dTmStmp) {
        this.dTmStmp = dTmStmp;
    }

    public MyTable getMyTable() {
        return myTable;
    }

    public void setMyTable(MyTable myTable) {
        this.myTable = myTable;
    }

}
```

I try this code, but unsuccessfully (getting `NULL` for `id`):

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
session.beginTransaction();
System.out.println("Before insert ->>> " + usr.getId() + " | " + usr.getLogin() + " <<<-");
Usr.UsrPK test = (Usr.UsrPK) session.save(usr);
session.getTransaction().commit();
System.out.println("After insert ->>> " + test.getId() + " | " + test.getLogin() + " <<<-");
```

Console output:

> Before insert ->>> null | login <<<-
>
> Hibernate: /* insert com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.fb.entity.Usr */ insert into USR (DTMSTMP, FNAME, MYTABLEID, ID, LOGIN) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> After insert ->>> null | login <<<-

Comment: You could read the user after commit thus you'll get the value generated by the sequence. Could you show the user entity? It sounds somewhat strange that you have different PK in database and persistence provider.

Comment: @SergeyPauk if I change `test` to `usr` in last line - get same result to console

Comment: Please include the code of the entities (and relevant XML config, if any) in the question itself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel add entity code, hibernate xml config and part of DAO class for test purpose. All console ouput `NULL` for `id` field

Comment: Please add them in the question itself. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Change your @EmbeddedId in Usr class with below

```
@EmbeddedId
private UsrPK id;
```

Add to UsrPK id variable the annotations

```
@Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "BIGINT", unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PK")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "PK", sequenceName = "GEN_USR_ID", allocationSize = 1)
```

Comment: Error: `Unable to find properties (login) in entity annotated with @IdClass:com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.fb.entity.Usr`

Comment: login is no more a variable of Usr, you schould access login by **Usr.UsrPK.login**  **usr.getId().getLogin()**

Comment: Of course, I changed my code, but compile error (property not found) at `SESSION_FACTORY = new MetadataSources(STANDARD_SERVICE_REGISTRY).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();`

Comment: remove **@IdClass(com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.fb.entity.Usr.UsrPK.class)** definition

Comment: Compiled successfully, record inserted, but return `NULL` for `id` in UsrPK

Comment: does it have value in DB?

Comment: Yes, `id` and `login` has values in db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88006/discussion-between-sgpalit-and-vladimir-zaytsev).